# Chrome Extension: Background.js values get erased/reset?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I declare a global variable in my **background.js** for my Chrome extension.

I  find that at various points in time it gets reset, as if background.js were run again, and sometimes it is actually NULL when I attempt to use it from within my Popup (but not always). I haven't been able to pinpoint exactly when this reset or loss occurs.

Has anyone noticed similar inconsistent behavior with global Background vars in Chrome extensions?

Comment: I believe I found the answer, I had this in my manifest.json:   "background": {
    "persistent": false, .. } After changing persistent=true, looks like it's working now. Not sure what setting it to FALSE does.

Comment: false = https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages

Comment: @geneb. Please post your solution as an answer, preferably with a link Rob W provided, and accept it - so the question doesn't hang unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that I had the following in my manifest.json:

```
 "background": { "persistent": false }
```

When I changed it to TRUE, it started working. For more info, see this link provided by Rob W.:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages

Comment: Not working in v3. Shows error that one should use "service_worker" instead